# Function using IF and AND and OR on a range of cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to use an IF function in combination with AND and OR. I have several columns with text and I want a `1` or `0` (true or false):

```
if (cell1:cell10 == 'stringA' AND ('stringB' OR 'stringC') then return '1'
```

otherwise, return '0'.

Comment: what happens with your current formula?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do - can you include some examples with desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware, not properly tested by me!:

```
=--AND(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("stringA",A:A,1,0))),OR(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("stringB",A:A,1,0))),NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("stringC",A:A,1,0)))))
```

Note I have covered the entire column cell1:cell10 (I assumed ColumnA) but range can be restricted to A1:A10 say, if desired.